# Can't XML or HTML Parse This Website in R

Tags: html, r, xml

I need to scrape this page to get the value of the comment, as well as the Document and Submitter Information on the right side..

https://www.regulations.gov/document?D=FDA-2014-N-1207-7673

I've tried using `read_html()` and `read_xml()` from the `xml2` package with no luck. I've tried `getURLContent()` followed by `xmlParse()` and `htmlParse()` from `RCurl`.

I even tried simply `readLines()`, which does not actually get me the content of the website.

I suppose I don't have a great understanding how this all works. Previous websites I have always been able to scrape with simply `html_parse()`, `html_nodes()` and `html_attr()`. How can I accomplish scraping this website?

Comment: You're not going to be able to with `rvest`. Try `seleniumPipes` or [`splashr`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr)

Comment: I downloaded your `splashr` and ran `doc = render_html(url = 'https://www.regulations.gov/document?D=FDA-2014-N-1207-7673')`. To get the comment, which lives in a `div`, I tried `html_nodes(doc, 'div') %>% html_text()`, which gives me back a line about JavaScript, which is what I'm trying to avoid by using `splashr`. `Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled in order for Regulations.gov to display correctly.` What can I do from here?

Comment: It seems `splashr` isn't doing it for me, unless I am using it incorrectly. I followed the steps on the GitHub page you linked for `splashr`, but my Mac cannot complete the command `sudo docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 hrbrmstr/splashttpd`. The `docker pull` command right before that ran just fine. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your help.